# .NET Entity Framework: Add-Migration is too slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on adding entity Framework onto our current web based project. Our project has 572 Tables currently. I'm looking at also switching our database handling to use Migrations instead of how we do it now (which is a bloated sql file that ends up becoming a hassle when we do merges). I created a test project to try out the Entity Framework on. was able to reverse the engineer the models (which takes some time, but worth the time for sure). Next Step, I ran Enable Migrations, created the first migration (which had EVERY table in the up method), that wasn't a big deal. the problem I'm having is when I added a property to a model, and then ran 'Add-Migration', it takes WAY TOO LONG. It's been running for about 40 minutes and all I'm doing is creating one column....it still hasn't finished. any ideas on how to speed this process up. or maybe even a way to create these migrations manually (as of right now, it might be easier for me to type in the AddColumn and DropColumn, instead of EF doing it automatically). Please help, I want to present this to my bosses as a viable option.

Comment: Are all of those tables/objects referenced in the DataContext or referenced object properties?  Keep in mind that EF is performing a comparison between your last migration and the one you're creating, so it's going to iterate through each object/property specified in your data context model.  Migration script generation isn't something that's meant to happen frequently, and it doesn't affect actual run-time.

Comment: Wow 40 minutes! I just timed mine and it took 55 seconds and I thought that was way too slow.

Comment: I too am encountering this with EF Core. I haven't been able to isolate the cause, never had this issue with EF6.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've defined your models in an assembly separate to that of your entry point (i.e. your web app, console app, etc).

Create a new app.config in your data assembly and define at least this:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

It is sometimes also necessary to define the connection string name when calling add-migration or update-database:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionStringName MyDB
Add-Migration MyMigration -ConnectionStringName MyDB
```

I'm unable to figure out what's different about a configuration that requires this though.

The add-migration slowness seems to occur when EF is unable to contact your database to try and get some information from it so it waits for a timeout before falling back on what it already knows about your database. You might discover that in this situation you cannot call Update-Database either - that's why.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the prior answer.   In the data project's csproj file, you may need to multi-target like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

I also found that I needed to add an IDesignTimeContextFactory like:

```
public class MyDbContextDesignTimeFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<LocationsDbContext>
{
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        //TODO - use configuration file/environment variable
        return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options, new RepositoryConfiguration()
        {
            DefaultConnectionString = "theConnectionString"
        });
    }
}
```

*In this case I'm using MySql Connector which configures the connection string in the OnConfiguring method of the DbContext, hence a configuration is normally injected so it can be used in that method.

I can then, in a terminal cd to the data project root and issue a "plain" command line like:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

And it runs much much quicker than trying to use the `--startup-project` option.